# Example of noncompact space in which every real valued continuous function on it is uniformly continuous

Tags: proof-verification, continuity, metric-spaces, compactness, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to find

> Example of non-compact metric space $(X,d)$ such that every real-valued continuous function is uniformly continuous

My attempt:

$X$ is an infinite set $d$ is a discrete metric. Any real-valued continuous function is constant due to totally disconnected ness of X.
Which is the trivially uniform continuous function

But As $X=\cup_{x\in X} B(x,1)$ which cannot have finite subcover as each ball contain a single point

Is my attempt is correct?

thanking you

Comment: If $X$ is discrete, then all functions are continuous. The argument should be that if you take $\delta<1$ then the condition $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $x=y$ (assuming taking that by discrete we take one that is bounded away from $0$, say by $1$). Therefore, it uniformly ensures that $d(f(x),f(y))=0<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, but for the wrong reason. In such a space, *every* real valued function is both continuous and uniformly continuous (just take $\delta=1$ in the definition of both, and you're done).

Comment: How is he right? The question is whether the attempt is correct. It is not.

Comment: He (or she) is right because it is true that in an infinite set with the discrete metric, every real-valued continuous function is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @mathworker21 Part of his attempt was to show $X$ is not compact which also is part of the assignment. That's OK. What's **not** true is that real-valued maps are constant.